# How would I mock a call to ioutil.ReadFile in go?

Tags: testing, go

I have the following function:

```
func ObtainTranslationStringsFile(path string) ([]string, error) {
    if contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path); err != nil {
        return ObtainTranslationStrings(string(contents))
    } else {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

I need to mock ioutil.ReadFile, but I'm not sure how to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: Go idiom is to use a guard clause and return the error (if any) in the first branch of the if, and avoid the `else`. That'd make the inverted if condition clearer without testing. http://play.golang.org/p/j7344KQe_y

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Don't mock `ioutil.ReadFile`. Once you mocked it, testing `ObtainTranslationStringsFile` wouldn't test any more than testing `ObtainTranslationStrings` would. If you need to test `ObtainTranslationStringsFile`, create a temporary file and pass its path to `ObtainTranslationStringsFile`. That way you will actually test the functionality that is added by that function.

Comment: I disagree. A test for `ObtainTranslationStringsFile` should not try exercise `ioutil.ReadFile`, it should exercise how `path`, `contents`, `err`, and the return value are handled. Thus `ioutil.ReadFile` can and should be mocked out. (And exercised only at integration test level)

Comment: One shouldn't need to exercise the "real ioutils.ReadFile" function to do unit test. The unit test for the function ObtainTranslationStringsFile should only testing the logic inside the function, but not the function it's calling. Therefore, if there is way, it's always preferred to mock ioutils.ReadFile to return error, and to not return error.

Comment: “Testing `ObtainTranslationStringsFile` wouldn't test any more than testing `ObtainTranslationStrings` would.” Not so. There’s logic in the former that’s not present in the latter — namely, what happens when `err == nil` vs. `err != nil`. That logic warrants its own testing. Unit tests for `ObtainTranslationStringsFile` should *not* assert/provoke “correct” behavior of/from `ioutil.ReadFile`. That’s not their responsibility. Their job is to assert correct behavior of `ObtainTranslationStringsFile` *in response to* (a mocked) `ioutil.ReadFile`. Of course, integration tests are another story…

Answer (score 19):

There are a couple of ways to handle this if you want to mock this. The first, and perhaps simplest, is to change from using [ioutil.ReadFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadFile), and instead call [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) which takes an io.Reader interface. It's pretty easy to then inject your own io.Reader/filesystem implementation per [this method](https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#8).

If you prefer not to change the method signature, the other option is to not use `ioutil`, and instead declare a function replacement for ReadFile. Injecting that would be easier with an object method rather than a function, but it's do-able. It just relies on package level variable magic that may seem distasteful to some. See the options explored below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    _ "log"
)

type ReadFile func(filename string) ([]byte, error)
// myReadFile is a function variable that can be reassigned to handle mocking in option #2
var myReadFile = ioutil.ReadFile

type FakeReadFiler struct {
    Str string
}

// here's a fake ReadFile method that matches the signature of ioutil.ReadFile
func (f FakeReadFiler) ReadFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(f.Str)
    return ioutil.ReadAll(buf)
}

func main() {
    payload := "PAYLOAD"
    path := "/dev/nul"
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(payload)

    // option 1 is more elegant, but you have to change the method signature to take an io.Reader
    result1, err := ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice1(buf)
    fmt.Printf("ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice1 == %#v, %#v\n", result1, err)

    // option 2 keeps the method signature, but allows you to reassign a the myReadFile variable to change the method behavior for testing
    fake := FakeReadFiler{Str: payload}
    myReadFile = fake.ReadFile
    result2, err := ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice2(path)
    fmt.Printf("ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice2 == %#v, %#v\n", result2, err)
}

func ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice1(rdr io.Reader) ([]string, error) {
    if contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rdr); err == nil {
        return []string{string(contents)}, nil
    } else {
        return nil, err
    }
}

func ObtainTranslationStringsFileChoice2(path string) ([]string, error) {
    if contents, err := myReadFile(path); err == nil {
        return []string{string(contents)}, nil
    } else {
        return nil, err
    }
}
```

Playground versions here: [sandbox](https://play.golang.org/p/-MfFrALz9X).

If you want to get more sophisticated, I recommend making a full on file system mock. It's what I typically do, and not as difficult as it sounds: https://talks.golang.org/2012/10things.slide#8. With your example, you weren't using structs and interfaces, which really makes this sort of mocking much more robust.

Comment: As of 2022.11, ioutil.ReadAll is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to mock an io.Reader here is a solution using https://github.com/stretchr/testify

In your package declare

```
type ioReader interface {
    io.Reader
}
```

This is only needed to tel mockery that you need such interface an it will generate the corresponding mock.

Then generate mocks

```
go get github.com/vektra/mockery/.../
mockery -inpkg -all
```

Then in your test code you can do that

```
str := "some string"
r := &mockIoReader{}
r.
    On("Read", mock.Anything).
    Run(func(args mock.Arguments) {
        bytes := args[0].([]byte)
        copy(bytes[:], str)
    }).
    Return(len(str), nil)
```